# Rails 3: Devise users_controller, where is it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

After I create a devise as Users, where is `users_controllers.rb`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Devise doesn't create a controller along with your model, so you have to generate it yourself:

```
rails g controller Users
```

Note that Devise uses its own internal controllers for things like session management and registrations. You can extend these, if you need to, but it is not mandatory.